# Permutation $\alpha^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

Show that there is no permutation $\alpha \in S_4$ so that $\alpha^2=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &3  &4  &2 
\end{pmatrix}$.

$S_4=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2 &3  &4 
\end{pmatrix}$

If $ \alpha=\begin{pmatrix}
2 &4  &3
\end{pmatrix}$, we get:
$$\alpha^2=\alpha\cdot\alpha=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4 \\ 
 1&4  &2  &3 \\1 
 &3  &4  &2 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Why can't I do that?

Comment: Cycle notation usually means $1\rightarrow3\rightarrow4\rightarrow2\rightarrow1$ (or similar).  So, you’re calculating a different permutation is a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\beta = (1 \ 3 \ 4 \ 2)$ is on odd permutation: a cycle of length equal to $4$. As the square of any permutation is even, $\beta$ can't be written as a square.